# NaN with 6 calculations

Tags: javascript

So I'm making a javascript game and things are going pretty fast and good.
Now for rendering the map, I'm using some nice calculations where and how to render the map. After the 6 calculations all the variables that were calculated end up being NaN. 
Can someone give me a hint?

```
Screen.prototype.renderMap = function(map) {
    var tileSize = map.tilewidth;

    var x = 0, y = 0, sx = 0, sy = 0, sectionWidth = 0, sectionHeight = 0;

    x += -(this.xOffset % tileSize) - tileSize;
    y += -(this.yOffset % tileSize) - tileSize;
    sx += (this.xOffset / tileSize) - 1;
    sy += (this.yOffset / tileSize) - 1;
    sectionWidth += (game.canvasWidth / tileSize);
    sectionHeight += (game.canvasHeight / tileSize);

    map.render(x, y, sx, sy, sectionWidth, sectionHeight);
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: console.log every variable you use after each line.

Comment: My guess "this.xOffset" or this.yOffset  or map.tilewidth or ... is NaN.

Comment: What value does tileSize have? My guess is zero.

Comment: what is the value of `tileSize`?

Comment: `map.tilewidth` should be `map.tileWidth`?

Comment: I suspect that tileSize === 0.

Comment: As a hint, console.log all your variables (especially map.tilewidth & tilesize) and see which one(s) aren't being set. Then, step through the js using firebug which should highlight on which specific line a NaN is being introduced. I'd guess tileSize isn't getting the correct value . . .

Comment: That is, _debug your code_.

Comment: plalx for some reason it was tileWidth, yes. This was the problem -.-

Answer (score 1):

That simply means that somewhere in your code lies an non-number value which you are using in your math equations.

Put a `debugger;` statement at the beginning of your function or use `console.log` to check every variables to make sure they have the expected value. I suspect one will be `undefined`.

```
isNaN(1 + undefined); //true
```